# What is the C++ iostream endl fiasco?

Tags: c++, iostream, endl

I was listening to a [google talk by Andrei Alexandrescu on the D programming](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlVpPstLPEc) language when he threw out a one liner about the "endl" fiasco. I just thought endl was the preferred way to signify the end of a line and flush the buffer for a stream. Why is it considered a fiasco? Should I not be using it in my code?

Comment: @ildjarn: You are 100% right. I knew that it flushes the buffers and still lost ~75 points in [CEOI 2008](http://ceoi2008.de/en/welcome) for that! Bad habits!

Comment: @ildjarn My teacher insists we use `std::endl` for everything rather than `\n`, which I agree is rather strange.  But then again, we're just writing simple console programs.  But then again again, he seems to think initializing a (POD) variable in a loop is a potential performance issue...

Comment: I added the link, also I found the link on http://erdani.com/

Comment: @Tod Thats Alexandrescus home page :)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

(I assume) He just means that many, especially new, C++ programmers use `std::endl` blindly instead of `'\n'` for newline, flushing unnecessarily frequently and potentially making the performance of their program abysmal.

I.e., most people are taught that `std::endl` is **the** canonical way to insert a newline into a stream even though it is very rarely *necessary* or appropriate to flush it.

It is some people's opinion (*cough*) that `std::endl` shouldn't even be in the standard, as it is so rarely appropriate and not a *significant* typing savings over `'\n' << std::flush` anyway.

---

**TL;DR**(s)**:**

- In the end, `std::endl` buys you nothing except *usually worse* performance and *usually more* typing.
- It has its uses, but they are considerably rarer than its frequency of use in most large codebases would suggest, therefore...
- Its utility is highly questionable and its ubiquity is absurd – a fiasco indeed!

Comment: It's only really an issue then if your program performs a lot of stream-based I/O.

Comment: AFAIK some people use it thinking that it's the "platform neutral" way to insert a newline, without knowing that `\n` **is** the newline in C, and that `\n`->platform specific line terminator conversion is handled by the stream.

Comment: Are we talking premature optimization here? It is nice to have a simple to use end-line thingy to use for your output. Especially if you are learning the language and don't immediately see what '\n' would do for output. After you have learned to profile your code, you can consider other options!

Comment: @Bo Persson : The larger issue (in my mind) is that if there were no `std::endl`, then people would be taught to use `'\n'` from the beginning, and as `'\n'` is shorter to type then `std::endl` (and the same as `endl`) I would say it's simple to use too. :-] In the end, `std::endl` buys you nothing except worse performance and usually more typing.

Comment: @Bo Persson : I guess another way of phrasing it would be, the existence and ubiquity of `std::endl` is a premature pessimization more-so than using `'\n'` is a premature optimization.

Comment: @ildjarn: it buys you nothing except worse performance, more typing *and* flushing. I have been bitten by it, adding traces to a program that was crashing to detect when/where and being confused because unless you flush, absence of the message in the output does not mean that the trace was not reached, it could have been reached and not flushed.

Comment: @David : Sure, if you need flushing, use `endl`; however, most people who use `endl` do _not_ need flushing.

Comment: why does `std::endl` flush anyway, when we have `std::flush`?

Comment: @Raildex it doesn't *just* flush. It's the "make sure this line reaches a terminal / log file" operator

Answer (score 0):

To add to the already great answer, this issue can be extended to the 'iostream' fiasco.

Using iostream in general has a performance penalty because it is designed to be synced up with the stdio streams (`printf` and `scanf`) so that you can use a mix of isotream and stdio if so desired.

If you are only going to be using one you can get a performance benefit by calling `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false)`. I believe, however, the unsynced streams are no longer thread safe...

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17940337) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9371717) as well as documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) .