#  How to can I print values using vectors and how can I add a value to the end of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have two questions:

**1- How can print the values of a for the code stated below???**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    list<int> a;

    for(i; i<5; i++)
    {
        a.push_back(i);
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

2- How can I add new element to an integer array? For example, I have an array such that:

```
int *a;
int size = 3
a = new int [size];

a[0]=0;
a[1]=1;
a[2]=2;

//Now, I would like to add a new element to my array by increasing its size by one

size += size; // new size is 4
```

How can I use my array with the new size and add a new element to the end of the array?

Answer (score 2):

(1)

```
list<int>::const_iterator it;

for (it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
    cout << *it << endl;
```

(2) Create a 2nd array with new[] and copy over the first.  Remember to delete[] the original.  Or, better yet, get rid of the array and use a vector and just push back the new element(s).  Vectors automatically resize themselves.

Comment: @Chad : Actually the *proper* way here would have been to use `const_iterator` rather than `iterator`, and prefix increment rather than postfix. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn - True but I think those subtleties are lost at this level of question.  I'll change anyway.

Comment: Never use `std::endl` when you mean `'\n'`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492380/what-is-the-c-iostream-endl-fiasco

Comment: And, never *ever* use `realloc` on a pointer returned by `new[]`.

Comment: @Rob - Are you done stating the obvious?  I'll take out the realloc because I didn't notice OP used new on the original array.  Endl stays because I wanted the buffer flushed so there would be no doubt OP would see the output.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should initialize i to 0 in the for() loop.
   To print the values you have to make another for() loop but instead of adding elements to the list you print them to cout.

   for(...)
   {
        // print to cout
   }
2. int* b = new int[size + 1];
   The you should use memcpy() to copy a into b, and then add the last element to b.
   At the end you should call delete for a and b also.

Comment: But, bear in mind that `memcpy` can only be used on [POD types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

**1**. Prefer `std` algorithms to hand-coded `for` loops:

```
std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(),
  std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

If hand-coding the loop is still the right choice, consider [Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/foreach.html):

```
BOOST_FOREACH(int i, list) {
  std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

**2** This is one reason why you should use `std` containers instead of pointers and arrays. Let somebody else debug the hard code.

```
int* newa = new int[newsize];
std::copy(a, a+std::min(newsize, size), newa);
delete[] a;
a = newa;
size = newsize;
```

But, does this code leave the extra items initialized or uninitialized? What exception guarantees does this code offer? Better to skip the `new` altogether and just declare a `std::vector`.