# Why use endl when I can use a newline character?

Tags: c++, string-formatting, iostream, buffering

Is there a reason to use `endl` with `cout` when I can  just use `\n`? My C++ book says to use endl, but I don't see why. Is `\n` not supported as widely as `endl`, or am I missing something?

Comment: To be clear, the vast majority of the time, you should **not** use `endl`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492380/what-is-the-c-iostream-endl-fiasco/5492605#5492605) + comments.

Comment: remember end-of-line is "\r\n" on a DOS/Windows platform and bare "\r" on some (all?) Mac platform, too.

Comment: @sylvainulg: That's not particularly relevant.  A '\n' character printed to a text stream will be automatically translated to the system's end-of-line representation.  There's no difference between `'\n'` and `std::endl` as far as that's concerned (the difference is the `flush`).  (Mac platforms, starting with OSX (I think) are Unix-based, and use `'\n'` to mark line endings.)

Comment: And if you do need to flush the stream as often as possible (e.g to see debug output before a crash), you could just use `std::cerr` which doesn't need explicit flushing either.

Comment: @keith: thanks for the precision. That wasn't very clear in the documentation I had at hand, and I didn't know myself about the flush difference.

Comment: @UncleBens: Yes, but `std::cerr` could easily go to a different file than `std::cout`.

Comment: This link also tells when to use flushing (`\endl`) and when just `\n` will do. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/185064/using-a-stream-manipulator-endl-or-a-newline-escape-character-n

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`endl` appends `'\n'` to the stream ***and*** calls `flush()` on the stream. So

```
cout << x << endl;
```

is equivalent to

```
cout << x << '\n';
cout.flush();
```

A stream may use an internal buffer which gets actually streamed when the stream is flushed. In case of `cout` you may not notice the difference since it's somehow synchronized (**tied**) with `cin`, but for an arbitrary stream, such as file stream, you'll notice a difference in a multithreaded program, for example.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220202104153/http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/214763-why-flush-a-stream/)'s an interesting discussion on why flushing may be necessary.

Comment: Also, isn't endl converted to the proper plataform EndLine symbol("\r\n" on windows, "\n" on Linux)?

Comment: The C standard specifies that `'\n'` is transparently converted to the appropriate character.  So, yes, since `endl` attaches a `'\n'`, this is happening.  But its not specific to `endl`.

Comment: Or, more precisely, you could write `(cout << x << '\n').flush();`. That is, all in just one statement now as `cout << x << endl;` is one statement.

Comment: @Nawaz: Eschew obfuscation and surplusage. Espouse elucidation

Comment: @Chad: Yes -- and so does the C++ standard, which is what we're discussing here.

Comment: @Keith Thompson The fact that the `'\n'` is transparently converted is not explicitly stated in the "C++" standard; it is something that carried over from the C standard.

Comment: @Chad: Hmm, I didn't know that.  But in that case, it's important to note that C++ inherits that rule from C.  (I'm trying to figure out where the C++ standard says that, but I find the C++ standard harder to read than the C standard.)

Comment: @Keith: There was a question around SO: "What can you do with C that you cannot do with C++". One of my favorite answers read: "I can lift the printed version of the annotated C standard 1000 times with one hand"

Answer (score 7):

`endl` is more than just an alias for the `\n` character. When you send something to `cout` (or any other output stream), it does not process and output the data immediately. For example:

```
cout << "Hello, world!";
someFunction();
```

In the above example, there's is *some* chance that the function call will start to execute before the output is flushed. Using `endl` you force the flush to take place before the second instruction is executed. You can also ensure that with the [`ostream::flush`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/flush/) function.

Comment: You mean 'or any other _buffered_ output stream`.

Comment: Why would someFunction() execute before the first line? what could cause such a thing?