# Formatting Output c++

Tags: c++, cout

Wanting to do some fancy formatting. I have several lines that I want to interact with each other. Get the first two lines. Print out the character in the second line times the integer in the first line. Seperate them all with a asterisk character. No asterisk after the final character is printed. Move onto the next integer and character. Print them on a separate line.  Do this for the whole list. The problem I am having is printing them on separate lines. Example:

```
5
!
2
?
3
#
```

Desired output:

```
!*!*!*!*!
?*?
#*#*#
```

My output:

```
!*!*!*!*!*?*?*#*#*#*
```

Below is my code. Another thing to mention is that I am reading the data about the characters and numbers from a separate text file. So I am using the getline function.

Here is a chunk of the code:

```
ifstream File
File.open("NumbersAndCharacters.txt")
string Number;
string Character;
while(!File.eof(){
  getline(File, Number);
  getline(File, Character);
//a few lines of stringstream action
  for (int i=0; i<=Number; i++){
      cout<<Character<<"*";}//end for. I think this is where
                            //the problem is.
  }//end while
File.close();
return 0;
```

Where is the error? Is it the loop? Or do I not understand getline?

It should be printing an "endl" or "\n" after each multiplication of the character is done.

Thanks to everyone for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown your code yet, but what seems to be the issue here is that you simply forgot to add a new line every time you print your characters. For example, you probably have done:

```
std::cout << "!";
```

Well, in this context you forgot to add the new line (`'\n'`), so you have two options here: first insert the new line yourself:

```
std::cout << "! \n";
```

Or `std::endl;`

```
std::cout << "!" << std::endl;
```

For comparison of the two, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324843/why-use-endl-when-i-can-use-a-newline-character). Without further description, or more importantly your code that doesn't seem to work properly, we can't make suggestions or solve your problem.

Comment: That doesn't address the second issue, the superfluous trailing `*` character.

Comment: @IInspectable well , he didn't show code so this is a complete prediction. I am guessing he printed using a for loop and he accidently had one more iteration than needed? But if he doesn't show code , how am i suppose to know what caused the " superfluous trailing `*` character" ?

Comment: You aren't supposed to know. Neither are you supposed to answer a question, that's off-topic.