# Issues with getline c++

Tags: c++, getline

Wanting to do some fancy formatting. I have several lines that I want to interact with each other. Get the first two lines. Print out the character in the second line times the integer in the first line. Seperate them all with a asterisk character. No asterisk after the final character is printed. Move onto the next integer and character. Print them on a separate line.  Do this for the whole list. The problem I am having is printing them on separate lines. Example:

```
5
!
2
?
3
#
```

Desired output:

```
!*!*!*!*!
?*?
#*#*#
```

My output:

```
!*!*!*!*!*?*?*#*#*#*
```

A chunk of the code. I am reading the data about the characters and numbers from a separate text file. So I am using the getline function.

Here is a chunk of the code:

```
ifstream File;
File.open("NumbersAndCharacters.txt")
string Number;
string Character;
while(!File.eof(){
  getline(File, Number);
  getline(File, Character);
//a few lines of stringstream action
  for (int i=0; i<=Number; i++){
      cout<<Character<<"*";}//end for. I think this is where
                            //the problem is.
  }//end while
File.close();
return 0;
```

Where is the error? Is it the loop? Or do I not understand getline?

It should be printing an "endl" or "\n" after each multiplication of a character is done.

I asked this question a few days ago. It did not include my code. It was put on hold. I edited the questions and flagged it for moderator review 24 hours ago. There has been no response from moderators or those who put it on hold, so I am re-asking.

Comment: where you think the `"endl" or "\n"` comes from?

Comment: The `std::getline` function does not place line ending characters into the input string.

Comment: Also note: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting Output c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820905/formatting-output-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the read character is the last of its line, just put "endl" instead of "*" since getLine() doesn't include the line return:

```
while(!File.eof(){
      getline(File, Number);
      getline(File, Character);
    //a few lines of stringstream action
      for (int i=0; i<=Number; i++){
          cout<<Character;
          if (i == Number)
              cout<<endl;
          else
               cout<<"*";
       }
    }//end while
```

Comment: Thanks! You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

`getline` wont read in the newline at the end of the line in your file. You also don't add a newline anywhere. In case you are confused, a newline is the character `'\n'` and represents a newline break (on windows it is usually "\n\r", newline carriage return).

You need to add your own newline:

```
for (int i=0; i<=Number; i++){
  cout<<Character;
  if (i != Number) {
      cout << '*';
  }
}
cout << "\n";
```