# Creating a function in c++ to output to designated source

Tags: c++, class, iostream

I want to have a function that outputs certain pieces of information to a specific designated source that is inputted to the function. In code, what I mean is:

```
function output( source ) {

source << "hello" << endl;

}
```

where source can be a `ofstream` or `cout`. So that I can call this function like so:

`output(cout)` or `ofstream otp ("hello"); output(otp)`

My question is, how do I characterize `source` to make this work? It's fair to assume that `source` will always be a member of the `std` class

Thanks!

Comment: Two asides: 1) `source` is on odd name for the place where data *goes to*. Doesn't data using *come from* a source? 2) Never say `endl` when you mean `'\n'`. See [`endl` fiasco](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492380/what-is-the-c-iostream-endl-fiasco/5492605#5492605).

Comment: @Rob: you're right, `source` should probably changed. And thank you so much about the `endl` fiasco. I didn't know that at **all**!! especially when my program is going to do a lot of I/O!!! Perfect comment, +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void output(std::ostream &source) {
    source << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

or even:

```
template <T>
void output(T &source) {
    source << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Write your function as:

```
std::ostream& output(std::ostream& source )
{
  return source << "hello" << endl;
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
output(cout);

//and 
ofstream otp ("hello"); 
output(otp);

//and
output(output(cout));
output(output(output(cout)));
output(output(output(output(cout))));

//and even this:
output(output(output(output(cout)))) << "weird syntax" << "yes it is" ;
```

---

By the way, if the `output` function has many lines, then you can write it as:

```
std::ostream& output(std::ostream& source )
{
  source << "hello" << endl;
  source << "world" << endl;
  //....
  return source;
}
```

The point is that it should return `source`. In the earlier version, the function returns `source`.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an `std::ostream&` as argument

Answer (score 1):

```
function output( source ) {
  source << "hello" << endl;
}
```

If this is a member function, the point of which is to dump data about objects of the class of which it is a member, consider renaming it to `operator<<`.  So, instead of

```
class Room {
  ...
  // usage myRoom.output(otp)
  void output(std::ostream& stream) {
    stream << "[" << m_name << ", " << m_age << "]";
  }
};
```

rather, try this:

```
class Room {
  ...
  // usage opt << myRoom << "\n"
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Room& room) {
    return stream << "[" << room.m_name << ", " << room.m_age << "]";
  }
};
```

That way, you can display the state of your class using a more natural syntax:

```
std::cout << "My Room: " << myRoom << "\n";
```

instead of the klunky

```
std::cout << "My Room: ";
myRoom.output(std::cout);
std::cout << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, redirecting output should be done at the user level. Write your C++ like this:

```
cout << "hello" << endl;
```

And when executing the application, user can redirect the output to whatever he wants, say a file:

```
myapp > myfile
```

Comment: You're certainly right, and I do plan to do that. But my application outputs a lot of information that is somewhat irrelevant for the calculations I'll need this specific file for. So I like to choose sources.

Comment: You can always filter the file, or just redirect only what you want, or use different output streams for each one. Just in case you didn't know, you can still redirect any output stream like this myapp 2> myfile, myapp 3> myfile and so on.