# C++ setw moving whole line not just the needed part

Tags: c++

I am trying to use setw to clean up the output of my program. I want the empty spaces in between "total number of spools to be ordered" and the output.

EDIT this is what im going for:

[image: example output]

and this is what I get
[image]
here is what I have so far:
UPDATED CODE

```
/********************************************/
// Name: results                             /
// Description: Print results                /
// Parameters: N/A                           /
// Reture Value: N/A                         /
/********************************************/
void results(int spoolnumber, int subtotalspool, float shippingcost, float totalcost)
{
  cout << left << setw (45) << "Total number of spools to be ordered is: " << right << spoolnumber << endl << endl;

  cout << left << setw (45) << "The subtotal for the spools is:" << right << "$" << subtotalspool << endl << endl;

  cout << "The shipping cost is: $" << shippingcost << endl << endl;

  cout << "The total cost is: $" << totalcost << endl << endl;

  return;
}
```

Comment: Rob's Rule #8: Never say `endl` when you mean `'\n'`. See [endl fiasco](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492380/what-is-the-c-iostream-endl-fiasco/5492605#5492605).

Comment: +1 for clarifying the question based on feedback

Comment: @ Steve Townsend: The better the question, the better the answers.

Comment: @ Hasturkun: thanks for adding the image code. forgot about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do

```
cout << left << setw (45) <<  "Total number of spools to be ordered is: " << spoolnumber << endl << endl;
```

to choose which side the padding goes. The default is left.

EDIT: using stringstream

```
stringstream ss;
ss << "$" << spoolnumber
```

I think you can fix the right end by adding another setw. So:

```
cout << left << setw (45) <<  "Total number of spools to be ordered is: " << right << setw(5) << ss.str() << endl << endl;
```

Comment: that isnt working either, i included a quick litle example image if that helps make my question more precise. EDIT: duh thats right, i need to use left and not right

Comment: that worked kinda, now the zeros dont line up. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/198/34267038.png/    I even added << right << after the text strings so the $ and number would be on the right

Comment: I think the problem is you are applying the setw to the $ sign. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but you can use stringstream to concat $ to the spoolnumber. See edit