# C++: right justified field ouput

Tags: c++

I wanna output a matrix in right-justified fields of length 8 in C++.
Is there any facility to make that easy to code?

Comment: don't use the C tag unless you are asking a C question / don't write C/C++ in the title if your question is about C++

Comment: in C the answer is : `printf("% 8d", x);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  std::right and std::setw to get right justified fields in iostream. The default padding char is space, but you can change it with `setfill()`. Also, `right` isn't strictly necessary as I believe it is the default, but it's nice to be explicit.

```
std::cout << std::right << std::setw(8) << data_var
```

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of `std::endl` when `'\n'` is more appropriate. See [`endl` fiasco](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492380/what-is-the-c-iostream-endl-fiasco/5492605#5492605).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `printf("%-8d", 1234);` ?

Comment: No. It left justifies the number.

Comment: Then try `printf("%+8d", 1234);` ?

Comment: If the question had been tagged C I would have done +1. But its not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
 std::right
```

will right justify and

```
std::setw(8)
```

will set the field width to 8.