# Why is Ruby string handling very slow?

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, time-complexity

**Sample input**

> 4
>   abcd
>   azazaz
>   abbzbba
>   flkjdh

**Sample output**

> 4
>   21
>   22
>   0

**Program in C++:**

```
#define ll long long
char s[1000010];

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    char x;
    scanf("%c",&x);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%s",s);
        int l=-1;
        int len=strlen(&s[0]);
        ll ans=0;

        for(int i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
        {
            if(s[i]=='a' || s[i]=='z')
            {
                ans+=((i-l)*(len-i));
                l=i;
            }
        }

        cout<<ans<<endl;
    }
}
```

**Program in Ruby:**

```
n = gets.chomp.to_i

ans = []

for x in 0..n-1
  str1 = gets.chomp
  l = str1.size
  count = 0
  i = 0
  le = -1

  str1.each_char do |cha|
    if(cha == 'a' || cha == 'z')
      count += (i-le)*(l-i)
      le = i
    end
    i += 1
  end
  ans[x] = count
end

puts ans
```

When considering longer strings, Ruby is 15 times slower than C++. Why?

Comment: You're comparing Ruby with C++ and then wondering why Ruby is slow? It is not Ruby's fault. It is all your fault that you're comparing in the first place. It is insulting to both languages.

Comment: BTW, C++ will be even more faster if you use `\n` instead of `endl` and disable the syncing C++ IOStreams with C IOStreams. [See my answer here for detailed explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17940337/415784) as to how to make C++ even more faster (compared to whatever language you use).

Comment: as @Nawaz says, don't get upset at a screwdriver from not being a hammer, and the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ and Ruby programs are not the same. The C++ program uses a `char` buffer for input - it "recycles" memory - while the Ruby program uses `gets`, which allocates new memory each time, which takes a toll on performance.

Also, the Ruby program uses an array to store the answer - and that array is being resized all the time! The C++ uses a single answer variable which it prints on each iteration - which is much faster.

Even if you change the programs to eliminate these two differences, the Ruby program will still be slower - but probably not by that much.