# Is it possible to create a constexpr byte string built at compile time via method chaining?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, constexpr, method-chaining

I was reading this recently: https://blog.mattbierner.com/stupid-template-tricks-template-assembler/#combing-byte-strings
and was curious if ByteString could be adapted to build a string at compile time using method chaining (returning *this). If so, how would this be done?

Comment: Like that article, *heaps of template voodoo*.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858141/conveniently-declaring-compile-time-strings-in-c), also `std::string_view` is a nice tool for making/using compile time strings.

Comment: It is a great article and I did already see that question but I couldn't find anything about combining this with method chaining.