# How to make a non-type template base class with non-template derived class

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to have a template base class and a non-template derived class? If so, what if the base class is a non-type template?

I am trying to pass a constexpr string to a non-template derived class but want to check the string during compile time in the class. I can make it work if I make the class a template but is there a way to do so if not a template?

An example of what I hope could work:

```
template<const char* name>
class Base
{
public:
    constexpr Base(){
        someFunction(name);
    }

    const char* base_name = name;
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    constexpr Derived(const char* name)
    {
        Base<name>();
    }

}
```

Comment: How is is`name` in `Derived`  constexpr?

Comment: `Base` is a template. `Base<...>` is a class. You can have a class as base, not a template.

Comment: The code was an outline and not meant to work. I'm trying to get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a template base class and a non-template derived class?

Yes, see `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC` in the example below.

> If so, what if the base class is a non-type template?

See `DDD`, `EEE`, `FFF` in the example below.

In C++20 you can have some kind of string-literal template arguments.
[This page](https://ctrpeach.io/posts/cpp20-string-literal-template-parameters) gives a concise example about their usage.

I'm not certain about your intention, and what is supposed to be `constexpr` or dynamic in your use case, but here is an attempt.
Some properties of the string-literals are checked at compile time thanks to `static_assert()`.

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++20 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // std::copy_n()

template<typename T> class AAA { public: T member; };
class BBB: public AAA<int> { };
class CCC: public AAA<double> { };

template<int N> class DDD { public: static constexpr int value=N; };
class EEE: public DDD<100> { };
class FFF: public DDD<1000> { };

template<size_t N>
struct StringLiteral
{
  constexpr StringLiteral(const char (&str)[N]) { std::copy_n(str, N, value); }    
  char value[N];
};

constexpr bool someFunction(const char *n) { return n[0]<n[1]; }

template<StringLiteral name>
class Base
{
public:
  static constexpr const char* base_name=name.value;
  constexpr Base() { static_assert(someFunction(base_name)); }
};

class Derived1: public Base<"def">
{
public:
  constexpr Derived1(int i): Base{}, i_{i} { }
  void f() { i_+=1; std::cout << base_name << ' ' << i_ << '\n'; }
private:
  int i_;
};

class Derived2: public Base<"ghi">
{
public:
  constexpr Derived2(int i): Base{}, i_{i} { }
  void f() { i_+=2; std::cout << base_name << ' ' << i_ << '\n'; }
private:
  int i_;
};

/*
class BadDerived3: public Base<"jhi"> // static_assert() fails
{
public:
  constexpr BadDerived3(int i): Base{}, i_{i} { }
  void f() { i_+=3; std::cout << base_name << ' ' << i_ << '\n'; }
private:
  int i_;
};
*/

int
main()
{
  AAA<char> aaa{'A'};
  BBB bbb{123};
  CCC ccc{45.67};
  std::cout << aaa.member << ' '
            << bbb.member << ' '
            << ccc.member << '\n'; // displays    A 123 45.67
  DDD<10> ddd{};
  EEE eee{};
  FFF fff{};
  std::cout << ddd.value << ' '
            << eee.value << ' '
            << fff.value << '\n'; // displays    10 100 1000
  // Base<"zbc"> bad_b; // static_assert() fails
  Base<"abc"> b;
  Derived1 d1{10};
  Derived2 d2{20};
  d1.f(); // displays   def 11
  d2.f(); // displays   ghi 22
  return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

After a comment about C++20 support, here is a modified version that works with C++11.
We cannot provide our own type as template parameter, but references are allowed.
The trick is to create a `constexpr` string-like data with static storage and reference it as a template parameter.
This is not as comfortable as the C++20 version, but it is still usable since each derived class only needs its `constexpr` name just before.
All of this is shamelessly inspired from the various answers on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15858141/11527076).

```
/**
  g++ -std=c++11 -o prog_cpp prog_cpp.cpp \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <iostream>

struct constexpr_str
{
  const char* const data;
  const std::size_t size;
  template<std::size_t N>
  constexpr constexpr_str(const char(&d)[N]) : data{d}, size{N-1} { }
};

constexpr bool someFunction(constexpr_str n) { return n.data[0]<n.data[1]; }

template<const constexpr_str &name>
class Base
{
public:
  static constexpr constexpr_str base_name{name};
  constexpr Base() { static_assert(someFunction(base_name), "bad_name"); }
};

constexpr auto derived1_name=constexpr_str{"def"};
class Derived1: public Base<derived1_name>
{
public:
  constexpr Derived1(int i): Base{}, i_{i} { }
  void f() { i_+=1; std::cout << base_name.data << ' ' << i_ << '\n'; }
private:
  int i_;
};

constexpr auto derived2_name=constexpr_str{"ghi"};
class Derived2: public Base<derived2_name>
{
public:
  constexpr Derived2(int i): Base{}, i_{i} { }
  void f() { i_+=2; std::cout << base_name.data << ' ' << i_ << '\n'; }
private:
  int i_;
};

/*
constexpr auto derived3_name=constexpr_str{"jhi"};
class BadDerived3: public Base<derived3_name> // static_assert() fails
{
public:
  constexpr BadDerived3(int i): Base{}, i_{i} { }
  void f() { i_+=3; std::cout << base_name.data << ' ' << i_ << '\n'; }
private:
  int i_;
};
*/

constexpr auto bad_base_name=constexpr_str{"zbc"};
constexpr auto base_name=constexpr_str{"abc"};

int
main()
{
  constexpr auto txt=constexpr_str{"ABCD"};
  static_assert(txt.size==4, "incorrect size");
  static_assert(txt.data[1]=='B', "incorrect char");
  // Base<bad_base_name> bad_b; // static_assert() fails
  Base<base_name> b;
  Derived1 d1{10};
  Derived2 d2{20};
  d1.f(); // displays   def 11
  d2.f(); // displays   ghi 22
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't use c++20 features right now. Is it still possible?

Comment: @domoremath I just edited with a variant that supports C++11.