# How to append const char* to a const char*

Tags: c++

I am trying to append three different const char* variables into one. This is because a function from windows library takes the parameter LPCTSTR.
I have the following code:

```
const char* path = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\";
const char* archivo = "vectors";
const char* extension = ".txt";

const char* fullPath =+ path;
fullPath =+ archivo;
fullPath =+ extension;
```

When I run it I get only the last (extension) added to to FullPath.

Comment: Pointers cannot be appended to pointers.

Comment: C-style strings don't support concatenation, and you do know what `const` means?. And what is `=+` supposed to be doing? Bottom line, use std::string.

Comment: `LPCTSTR` is not synonymous with `const char*`, by the way. This is a long pointer to a constant `TCHAR` array. `TCHAR` is transient, and can mean either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on how your software is setup. If you are using a Win32 function that takes an `LPCTSTR`, I would suggest you don't do that... the Win32 API has `A` and `W` variants for all string functions and any code that uses `char *` should be using the `A` variant.

Comment: i think if you just use `const wchar_t*` with wcscat all be cool

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to allocate some space to hold the concatenated strings. Fortunately, C++ has the `std::string` class to do this for you.

```
std::string fullPath = path;
fullPath += archivo;
fullPath += extension;
const char *foo = fullPath.c_str();
```

Be aware that the space containing the concatenated strings is owned by `fullPath` and the pointer `foo` will only remain valid so long as `fullPath` is in scope and unmodified after the call to `c_str`.

Comment: Since the OP didn't know about strings (I suppose), it might be valuable to add that the returned pointer is only valid while fullPath is in scope.

Comment: This doesn't address compile-time addition of `const char *`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to construct *at compile-time* a bunch of string literals, some of which are concatenations of other string literals, the most basic idiomatic low-maintenance technique is based on the good-old preprocessor

```
#define PATH "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\"
#define NAME "vectors"
#define EXT  ".txt"

const char *path = PATH;
const char *archivo = NAME;
const char *extension = EXT;

const char *fullPath = PATH NAME EXT;
```

However, the same thing can be achieved in more moden way by using some `constexpr` and template meta-programming magic (see [C++ concat two `const char` string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292237/c-concat-two-const-char-string-literals)).

Otherwise, you will have to resort to run-time concatenation (like `std::string` and such). But again, if the input is known at compile time, then a run-time solution is a "loser's way out" :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `const char*` you can't change the chars to which are pointing. 
So append `const char*` to a `const char*` is not possible!