# Homework: C++ Templates With Vectors

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I have to create a function that takes in a vector of unknown item types. 
Here is my code:

```
template <typename S>
void printVector(vector<S*> c){
   typename vector<S>::const_iterator A = c.begin();
   for (int A; A != c.end(); A++){
       cout<<c[A]<<" ";
   }
   cout<<endl;
}
```

In my main class here is my vector and function call:

```
vector<int> x;
int j=5;
for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
    x.push_back(num[i]);
}
printVector(x);
```

When I try to compile this code I get these errors:

> exercise1_1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   exercise1_1.cpp:33:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘`printVector(std::vector<int>&)`’
>   exercise1_1.cpp:33:15: note: candidate is:
>   exercise1_1.cpp:13:7: note: `template<class S> void printVector(std::vector<S*>)`

Comment: A vector of 'S' or a vector of pointer to 'S'? What type is 'std::vector<>::end()'? Is that comparable with 'int' as in 'A != c.end()'?

Comment: Do me a favour; mouse over the homework tag.

Comment: sorry @chris I'm not as familiar with this site as you but okay.. It is a vector of type 'S' and end() returns an iterator referring to the end element in the vector container.

Comment: @user1672267: Then `vector<S*>` is a typo and so is `int A`. In fact I think you just wrote `int A` because you're used to seeing `int` declarations in that part of a `for` construct, but it's not correct in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename S>
void  printVector(const std::vector<S>& c){
   typename std::vector<S>::const_iterator A = c.begin();
   for (; A != c.end(); A++){
       std::cout<<*A<<" ";
   }
   std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

Fixes:

- Your function was declared to take a `vector<S*>` but you obviously want it to take `vector<S>`.

  - Your main function invoked print_vector with an argument of `std::vector<int>`. Since an `int` is not an `S*` for any type of `S`, the template did not apply.
- You have redeclared `A` when you intended to use only the first declaration.
- You conflated indexed access to the vector with access through the iterator.

  - If you have an int: `c[i]`
  - If you have an iterator: `*it`

Less critical fixes:

- Avoid `using namespace std;`
- Never use `std::endl` when you mean `"\n"`.
- You should pass the parameter by const reference, not by value

Comment: Rob, the reason the `homework` tag is obsolete is that Stack Overflow encourages **all** answers to consist of dialog and explanation, rather than spoonfeeding code dumps.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - right. That's the point of the dialog that follows the code dump.

Comment: It wasn't there to begin with, and you know it ;) * > FGIW

Comment: Since you're streaming only `\n`, why not `std::cout << '\n';`?

Comment: Yeah, I enter the answer incrementally and save my work often. I need to rethink that strategy.

Comment: "*why not `'\n'`*?" - No good reason. My fingers know `"` better than `'`.

Comment: Why would the OP not mean `std::endl`? Flushing the output at the end of the line seems like a sensible think to do here.

Comment: @Grizzly - Either the OP directed the output to an interactive console or he directed to a file. If it is a console, the runtime will automatically flush the output at the end of the line, and he gains nothing. If it is a file it doesn't matter if it is flushed (unless his program crashes), and he gains nothing and loses performance.  *Maybe* OP meant to use `endl`. In my experience, 99% of people who use `endl` don't require or intend the flush.

Comment: @Grizzly : See also this question: [What is the C++ iostream endl fiasco?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5492380/636019)

Answer (score 3):

There were some errors in your code. Let's look at them:

- In the signature of `printVector`, you take a parameter of type `vector<S*>`. This means that, for a given type `S`, you take a vector of pointers to `S`. So, for example, if the type is `int`, you should 'send' a `vector<int*>`. In your example, you are attempting to 'send' a `vector<int>`, so the signature of `printVector` should look like this:

  ```
  template <typename S>
  void printVector(vector<S> c)
  ```
- In your for loop, you are declaring the variable `A` again, as `int`. In the C++ standard library, you can access every item in a vector using iterators or just accessing them like an array. You were mixing both things.

If you want to loop using iterators, it should look like this:

```
typename vector<S>::const_iterator a = c.begin();
for (; a != c.end(); a++){
    cout<<*a<<" ";
}
```

Which means, for every item in the vector, print its value (notice I used `*a` because I'm using iterators).

Or using the index-based approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++){
   cout<<c[i]<<" ";
}
```

Also, as a common practice in C++ community, use a const reference when receiving variables of non-primitive types. This prevents that a copy of the object is performed, so it will probably be faster when dealing with huge collections. Example:

```
 void printVector(const vector<S>& c)
```

So here is a full working example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename S>
void printVector(const vector<S>& c){
   for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++){
       cout<<c[i]<<" ";
   }
   cout<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    vector<int> x;
    int j=5;
    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
        x.push_back(i);
    }
    printVector<int>(x); // Can be printVector(x); too
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would the compiler fail to deduce the template arguments in this case? `printVector(x)` should be perfectly fine

Comment: I just wasn't sure if the C++ compilers actually infer the type.. But as they do, I just edited it. Thanks for the comment