# How to start a newline in C++ while doing equations

Tags: c++

Im reading through "The C++ Programming Language" and my current assignment is to make a program that takes two variables and determines the smallest, largest, sum, difference, product, and ratio of the values.

Problem is i can't start a newline. "\n" doesn't work because i have variables after the quote. And "<< endl <<" only works for the first line. I googled the hell out of this problem and im coming up short.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() {char ch;cin>>ch;}
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    cout<<"Enter value one\n";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Enter value two\n";
    cin>>b;
    (a>b); cout<< a << " Is greater than " << b;
    (a<b); cout<< a << " Is less than " << b;

    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: note that the difference between a `"\n"` and `std::endl` is that the latter includes a `flush`; this will make no difference for you in this case.

Comment: You can chain `<<` as you have already done: `if (a > b) cout << a << " is greater than " << b << "\n";`. Note that `(a > b);` by itself has no effect; it merely computes whether `a` is greater than `b` and does nothing with the result. You want `if (condition) { ... }` for conditional branching.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for `std::endl`, but your code won't work as you expect.

```
(a>b); cout<< a << " Is greater than " << b;
(a<b); cout<< a << " Is less than " << b;
```

This is not a condition, you need to rewrite it in terms of

```
if(a>b) cout<< a << " Is greater than " << b << endl; 
if(a<b) cout<< a << " Is less than " << b << endl;
```

You can also send the character `\n` to create a new line, I used `endl` as I thought that's what you were looking for. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492380/what-is-the-c-iostream-endl-fiasco) on what could be issues with `endl`.

The alternative is written as

```
if(a>b) cout<< a << " Is greater than " << b << "\n"; 
if(a<b) cout<< a << " Is less than " << b << "\n";
```

There are a few "special characters" like that, `\n` being new line, `\r` being carriage return, `\t` being tab, etc... useful stuff to know if you're starting.

Comment: There is no good reason for him to prefer `std::endl` over `"\n"` in this program, and there is reason for him to prefer `"\n"` generally. Google "endl fiasco."

Comment: @Robᵩ, you do realize that it's probably his first C++ program and that he simply wants a new line? `endl` is probably how it's explained in the book too... haven't read it in years

Comment: Updated the question with a more detailed answer

Comment: @emartel - Thanks for updating the question. I think we have an obligation to show first-program programers a better way, particularly when it comes to `std::endl`, `using namespace std;`, and other widely-taught mistakes.

Comment: @Robᵩ I guess I have to agree with you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can output `std::endl` to the stream to move to the next line, like this:

```
cout<< a << " Is greater than " << b << endl;
```