# C++ Vector giving incredibly unexpected value

Tags: c++, windows, vector, codeblocks

I have this code:

```
std::vector <int> loc;
loc.push_back(cpx);
loc.push_back(cpy);
loc.push_back(play.GetSize().x);
loc.push_back(70);
std::cout<<loc[3];
```

in a game I am making but even when I print the value of loc[2] and loc[3] they are completely different than they should be, when I run this code I get loc[3] equaling 70070 instead of 70. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: not a lot of info to go on... what are `cpx`, `cpy`, `play`?

Comment: I just noticed that both loc[3] and loc[4] ALWAYS give me values that are around 1000 times to large and have a couple of random digits on the very last two digits. I'm not entirely sure what this means but I do know that loc[0] and loc[1] do not have any problems whatsoever.

Comment: @filipe cpx is the current x of my "player" it currently starts at 5 and stays there unless I push a button to move it. cpy is the same only for y and it starts at 0 and goes towards 600 at an accelerating rate. play is the name of the instance of Sprite I am using. I'm using the SFML library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have another `cout` without an `endl` or `\n` somewhere in your code that you forgot to remove. That one prints the `700`, while the `70` is the correct output of the last line in your code sample.

Change your last line to `std::cout<< " and loc[3] is: " << loc[3] << std::endl;` to see that my wild guess is right, then go hunting for that other cout.

Comment: wow... you totally nailed it... added an endl to the end of that print statement to double check and that solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for your psychic debugging skills. @Roboinventor : `endl` is overkill 99% of the time – see [What is the C++ iostream endl fiasco?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5492380/636019).

Comment: @Robo That might not be the right lesson to take away from this - always consider `'\n'` vs `std::endl` depending on whether you want the buffer to be flushed instantly.

Comment: thats true but at least for now while I'm just using these statements to help debug it doesn't make much difference

Comment: @perfanoff I checked the code and you are right, it was 70,0,70 rather than 70,700