# I am getting a c++ program crash when trying to display a string diagonally

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, loops

My program is crashing when I run it, I ran the debugger and it reports this:
`std::out_of_range` at memory location 0x0066F6F4.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string name = "Alexi";

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= name.length(); i++) {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x <= i; x++)  {
            if (i == x) std::cout << name.at(x);
            else std::cout << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sigh. `i <= name.length()` makes you iterate one too many times and access out of bounds.

Comment: C++ arrays are [0-indexed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) meaning that while the length is 5, the index starts from 0 and goes to 4. Therefore you need to stop your loop iteration 1 before length (ie: `i < name.length()`)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `'\n'` is not platform-specific. The I/O system *has to* translate it to whatever is appropriate for expressing a newline. Actually, `'\n'` is preferable in certain situations (since it doesn't force flushing the stream like `std::endl` does).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `\n` **is** the newline in C, and that *`\n` to platform specific line terminator conversion* is handled by the stream [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492380/what-is-the-c-iostream-endl-fiasco)

Comment: I don't think the downvotes are justified. OP gave a fully working example showing the problem. Just because it's a relatively simple problem with a simple fix doesn't mean it's not worthy of SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have `i < name.length()` and not `i <= name.length()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string name = "Alexi";

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x <= i; x++)  {
            if (i == x) std::cout << name.at(x);
            else std::cout << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now this is wrong. The inner loop condition needs to be `x <= i` else this will not display anything but spaces.

Answer (score 2):

The string `name` has the length of 5.

Internally, it is stored in a `char []` (character array) called `name`where the

- character `A` is stored at `name[0]`
- character `l` is stored at `name[1]`
- character `e` is stored at `name[2]`
- character `x` is stored at `name[3]`
- character `i` is stored at `name[4]`

So note that the length was 5 but your **maximum index is 4.**

This is because C and C++ arrays are [0-indexed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)