# Overload put operator (<<) to recursively print out elements of an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I am trying to write code to recursively print out the elements of an array using an overload put operator (<<) in C++. However, I only know how to do this using non recursion. Would someone help me in translating this to do it recursively? My code is below and thanks in advance.

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outA, Recur a){

    for (int i = 0; i < a.aSize; i++){

            outA << a.aArray[i] << " ";   

    }
    outA <<  endl ;

    return outA;
}
```

Comment: What's `Recur`?

Comment: use static variable

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion?  It does not lend itself to large data structures as you have a lot of function calls to do.

Comment: [endl fiasco](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492380/what-is-the-c-iostream-endl-fiasco)

Comment: @Raindrop7: No, don't.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outA, Recur a) {

    if (a.size() > 0) {
        outA << a.aArray[0] << " ";
        Recur b;
        b.aArray = &a.aArray[1];
        b.setSize(a.size() - 1);
        return outA << b
    }
    else {
        outA << endl;
        return outA;
    }
}
```

Don't know what Recur is so I assume there is a pointer to array and a size property. The idea is to output one element and call recursively with a smaller array.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ops, will fix thansk

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only mean c-style arrays (where the size is part of the type definition), and not a pointer, you could roll out the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T, size_t N>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outA, T (& arr)[N]) {
    outA << arr[0];
    T (&next)[N-1] = reinterpret_cast<T(&)[N-1]>(arr[1]);
    outA << next;
    return outA;
}

template<typename T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outA, T (& arr)[1]) {
    outA << arr[0];
    return outA;
}

int main() {

    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

Even though it [works](http://ideone.com/fdsQcX), it has all the overhead of recursion for a very simple task. Not to mention that ugly `reinterpret_cast` just so I could treat the tail of the array as an array of a smaller size...
And also like **NathanOliver** said, you'd stamp out a separate function for each step in the recursion.

So in closing, I sincerely hope your question is purely academic.

---

A less awful implementation can be achieved if you use `operator<<` as only a wrapper that extracts the array size, and then calls the real function.

```
template<typename T>
void printArr(ostream& outA, T *a, size_t n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        outA << *a;
        printArr(outA, a + 1, n - 1);
    }
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outA, T (& arr)[N]) {
    printArr(outA, arr, N);
    return outA;
}
```

In this version: there only two function instantiations per invocation, there is no ugly casting, and the actual recursive call looks like a traditional recursive call.

Comment: This is also going to stamp out N functions where N is the size of the array right?

Comment: @NathanOliver, afraid so. Than again it [may be unrolled](https://godbolt.org/g/RzY0NY)

Comment: Is that `reinterpret_cast` valid?

Comment: @0x499602D2, According to [\[5.2.10/11\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#11), for lvalues, casting to a lvalue reference has the same effect as casting the address of the lvalue and dereferencing. Now, I couldn't find any explicit mention in the standard about array references decay. But since arrays will decay to pointers to the first element... I think it's valid, yet I'll retract that if proven wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Here is some pseudocode:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& outA, Recur a) {
    if(a.isEmpty())
         return outA;
    outA << a.first();
    outA << a.tail();
}
```

It will work if you have operator<< defined for single element.
a.tail() means all the elements of a without the first.

Comment: I belive this is infinite loop, because you never modify the array, so `!a.empty()` is always true. Remove the while and put `return` before `outA << a.tail();` to get tail recursion.